# A method like .hasAttrAndValue() for attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

Given situation:

```
$('#dbBoxNames > .names').each(function () {
    var boxName = $(this).attr('data-name');
    $('#boxList > .box[data-name="' + boxName + '"]').show();
});
```

I want to update multiple boxes which have `data-name` attribute equal to `boxName` variable.

When `boxName` has double quotes in the value, for ex. `box1"`, jQuery (2.4) throws `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .box[data-name="box1""]`.

The importance of using attribute data selector is simpler code and faster app.
Any ideas on how to solve this? (Using attribute data selector is a must)

**I am looking for something like:**

`$('.box').hasAttrAndVal('data-name', boxName);`
which I guess it wouldn't throw the same error anymore.

The following won't work:

- Replacing `'` with `"` and vice-versa (`boxName` can contain a single quote).
- Not using any quotes around the attribute value (`boxName` can contain a space).
- `boxObj[0].hasAttribute("' + boxName + '");` (there are multiple `.box` objects)

**Update 1**

If `boxName` contains either only single quotes or double quotes, the following seems to solve the problem:

```
$('#dbBoxNames > .names').each(function () {
    var boxName = $(this).attr('data-name');
    if (boxName.includes("'") && !boxName.includes('"'))
        $('#boxList > .box[data-name="' + boxName + '"]').show();
    if (!boxName.includes("'") && boxName.includes('"'))
        $("#boxList > .box[data-name='" + boxName + "']").show();
});
```

Now the problem is how to handle the case when `boxName` contains both single and double quotes...

**Solution**

Apparently I will resolve this bug by converting all special chars from DB into html codes. (The backend was not provided by me so this idea didn't cross my mind at first).

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code where such a value (with single and double quotes) is given? `<div class="name" data-name="&#34;andy&#39;">`?

Comment: Good point. I haven't found one yet, but I think if there is one it will either break the html or just convert to code as you wrote. Anyway, I don't even know why I didn't convert all those symbols to html code, which is the solution I will stick to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to escape the doublequotes:

```js
var boxName = 'box1"';
boxName = JSON.stringify(boxName);
$('#boxList > .box[data-name=' + boxName + ']').show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="boxList">
  <div style="display:none;" class="box" data-name='box1"'>Here I am!</div>
</div>
```

**Note** that `JSON.stringify()` also wrap the returned string into doublequotes.

Comment: I cannot modify `boxName` because it can contain value `box1"` and also `box1` which, after filtering, would be the same, hence generate a logic error.

Comment: The idea is that above is a simplified version of my problem. In reality, there can be up to 20'000 different values for `boxName` all in the same page. (I'm trying to do a filter)

Comment: Yes it can be different values. It just escape the quotes to be a valid selector. In my example is `var boxName = 'box1"';` just to show that it works with doublequotes in value.

Comment: But then it doesn't match the corresponding value, ruining the filters. I am updating my question above a little.